# I am looking for a way to use my old samsung galaxy note 3 as the touchscreen for my raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, usb, display

I have an old galaxy note 3 and I was looking to use that to replace the radio head unit in my car. I want to have the raspberry pi run the system and the galaxy note would basically be the screen for it.

I saw a tutorial for using a usb tether to accomplish this. 
link: http://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/

The problem I am having is that after I save the code for the usb0 network and reboot, the new usb0 does not show up in ifconfig.

Does anyone know of a different way to set up a usb network interface for a wired usb connection? Or know if something in the tutorial is possibly wrong for my particular pi?

Help much appreciated.

My Pi:
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1
Raspberry Pi 2014

Running Raspbian

edit:

File: /etc/network/interfaces

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

## Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd

```
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.42.42
netwrok 192.168.42.0
broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

edit 2: The tablet would be a permanent fixture and does not have data plan.

Comment: Add the content of your `/etc/network/interfaces` to your question.

Comment: Configuring an interface is not the same as creating the interface; e.g., if you have a wifi configuration but the adapter is not there, obviously the configuration won't work.  Check `ifconfig -a` (`-a` meaning, all, even if not up or configured) or (better) `ip link` and see if there is any USB interface at all mentioned.  If so, but it is not called `usb0`, that's the problem, and you may have to delve into something called [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) to give the phone a consistent device node name.

Comment: In any case editing in the output from `ip link` with the phone connected would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I use a raspberry pi as a Car Media Server myself for playing music via the headunit and streaming films and videos to my kids devices. Therefore i create a local wifi network with the pi as access point. For maintenance I can use a vnc server running on the pi and displayed on my android using a vnc client.

Instead of connecting your phone via usb you also could use such approach. Big advantage is that there is no wired connection necessary.

Edit:

I followed (mostly) this guide: http://www.gavsworld.net/?page=Raspberry+Pi/Car+Media+Server
Though I use the logitech media server for music (just because I am used to around my house) and a minidlna server for streaming video.

Answer (score 1):

They both server the same purpose. Store and play media. You would still need the amplifier from your head unit. I would suggest using the the head unit aux in to connect your tab from headphone out, and a well mounted tab would make a neat touchscreen car media player.

Your tab already has SIM to connect to a network, GPS, etc, so you can use it for navigation, handsfree, etc.

A better project for the pi would be to use the display from an old laptop. With bluetooth keyboard and mouse you could make a proper entertainment system for your car, more suited for a larger car/van, and you are not the driver. So you can play games, etc. Have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SOXMDb4cjI).

Comment: @goldilocks, i do actually. was inspired by the video i linked and i did it. the kits are available all over the net. i got mine from aliexpress, but they are on ebay too.

Comment: All apologies -- I missed that part (I never watch video links, and you did not mention you'd actually done this).  You might want to then mention explicitly that using the laptop screen requires a kit!

Comment: Its in a '96 truck and the current radio is stock with no aux, cd, or tape so the pi has to be the main system and the phone would need to be the monitor. I have an amplifier and speaker system already so I just need the audio out from the pi and to control it with the phone screen.

Comment: This what you are looking for? [How to control your PC with your Android phone](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033284/how-to-control-your-pc-with-your-android-phone.html)

Comment: Also found a [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Adding-a-direct-line-in-to-your-car-stereo-for-an-/) for adding a direct line-in to a 99 Chevy pick-up.

Comment: Yes that is the concept I want of controlling it but that method requires both of them to be on the same router which I wouldn't have in the car

Comment: Here is a Raspberry Pi2 guide for [HOWTO: Use Android Tablet as a screen / keyboard](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18916&p=331361)